# Printing A class with 3D Array field

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a class which is :

```
 public class CCTest {
 public double f;
 public double[][][] x;
 public double counter;
 };
```

and i have assigned  random number to x,

```
    CCTest[] cls = new CCTest[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
    cls[i] = new CCTest();
  }

   for (int i = 0; i < (Size = 5); i++) {
   cls[i].x = new double[this.c][this.D][this.Size];
   for (int j = 0; j < this.D; j++) {
    cls[i].x = getRandomX(this.c, this.D, this.Size);
  }
 }
```

then I tried to display the result using :

```
   public static void display(double[][][] array) {

    int rows = array.length;
    int columns = array[0].length;
    int depth = array[0][0].length;

    for (int d = 0; d < depth; d++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                System.out.print(array[r][c][d] + " ");
            }
          System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The Random Generation method is :

```
      public static double[][][] getRandomX(int x, int y, int z) {
      double[][][] result = new double[x][y][z];
      Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
                result[k][j][i] = r.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

but the output is empty [] , any idea please

Comment: what are the values of this.c, this.D, this.Size

Comment: @ Thusitha : this.c=2; this.D=2,  and for example ; This.size=10

Comment: Could you please show the code in getRandomX() as its whats initializing the array

Answer (score 0):

Your `display` method should rather look like:

```
public static void display(double[][][] array) {
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < array[x][y].length; z++) {
                System.out.println(array[x][y][z]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is another question which comes to my mind. What is getRandomX? You haven't shown us. I'd use the following:

```
public static double[][][] getRandom3DArray(double[][][] array) {

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < array[x][y].length; z++) {
                array[x][y][z] = r.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

You're mistaking `rows` with `depth` in your display.

Comment: @Nyakiba it's different a lot, as it gives the correct `getRandom3DArray` function. He has an error there.

Comment: @xenteros i add the random generation method , iam adding the argument to the method : `cls[i].x = getRandomX(this.c, this.D, this.Size);`  , and they are changing

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop :    for (int j = 0; j < this.D; j++) {...} is useless so you can remove this.The display and getRandomX() functions are fine. Try this in main , works in my environment:

```
    CCTest[] cls = new CCTest[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
        cls[i] = new CCTest();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (Size = 5); i++) {
        cls[i].x = new double[c][D][S];
        cls[i].x = getRandomX(c, D, S);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (Size = 5); i++) {
        display(cls[0].x);
    }
```